Is there a way to balance data in R without reordering a dataframe?
First, here is some toy data:
df <- data.frame(
  "stim" = c("face", "object", "pareidolia", "face", "face", "object", "pareidolia", "object"),
  "RT" = c(23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 22, 25, 23),
  "Opac" = c(70, 60, 80, 65, 60, 61, 59, 70)
)

I want to ensure that there are equal numbers of each stim variable in the dataset. I am using the following code to attempt this:
library(dplyr)

newdf <- df %>%
  mutate(mn = min(table(stim))) %>%
  group_by(stim) %>%
  sample_n(mn[1]) %>%
  ungroup()

This works almost perfectly, except that it reorders the data. My desired output would look like the following:
stim   RT   Opac
face   23   70
object 24   60
pareidolia 25 80
face   26   65
object 22   61
pareidolia 25 59

But this code outputs this:
stim   RT   Opac
face   23   70
face   26   65
object 24   60
object 22   61
pareidolia 25 80
pareidolia 25 59

I realize that this is likely happening because I am using table(), but I'm not sure how else to go about this. Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Also, bonus side question: is there a way to determine (a function, code snippet, etc) the row number where the data is being cut from as part of this process?

Hey, commas after "pareidoilia" are missing in df.

Ah- thank you for catching that! Sorry- very tired today. I'll edit this now!

You could use a filtering strategy rather than slice_n
df %>%
  mutate(mn = min(table(stim))) %>%
  filter(sample(seq_along(stim)) <= mn, .by=stim)


Thank you! I had to clear a bug in my code to get it to work, but now this runs beautifully. I appreciate your help!

Another possible solution "kind of" a slice_head but with filter:
> filter(df, .by = stim, row_number() <= min(count(df, stim)$n))
        stim RT Opac
1       face 23   70
2     object 24   60
3 pareidolia 25   80
4       face 26   65
5     object 22   61
6 pareidolia 25   59

Edit. A random alternative:
set.seed(10)
> dplyr::semi_join(df, slice_sample(df, by = stim, n = min(count(df, stim)$n)))
# Joining with `by = join_by(stim, RT, Opac)`
        stim RT Opac
1       face 23   70
2 pareidolia 25   80
3       face 27   60
4     object 22   61
5 pareidolia 25   59
6     object 23   70


Yes, so "kind of" a slice_head, since this one too messes up the row order (or sorts it). But I just added a random alternative :-) !
